# Authorize at web app with access token from web api

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, authorization, asp.net-core, openiddict

I have a web api connected to a database, which provides access tokens using OpenIddict and the password flow (Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant):

```
services.AddOpenIddict<TestUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, CompleteContext, Guid>()
                .EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token")
                .AllowPasswordFlow()
                .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                .DisableHttpsRequirement()
                .AddEphemeralSigningKey();
```

The web api has protected actions, which only can be called with a valid access token. This is working fine.

I have a web app which should use the same access tokens for authorization. The user enters his credentials and the web app sends them to the API to get an access token. I thought, that the web app can use this access token for authorization, but I don't now how to set up the middleware in asp.net core.

Background:
The web app and the web api should run on different servers and later I want to create mobile applications, which use the web api to access the data. That is why I want to use tokens. I want the web api to be the only project with access ot the database.

Edit more background:
The web app is a mvc 6 app, with standard user functionality: register, login, logout, email confirmation and some interactions with user generated content. All of this content should be stored in a database. Because I may need to add a mobile application later I want to have a separated web api for storing and accessing the data in the database. The only purpose of the web api is handling the data access. The mvc web app should communicate with the web api to get and store the data. The user has to be authenticated to use the web app and the web app must be authenticated to access the web api. There are no third party applications, which made me think of the password flow. I thougt, that the user enters his credentials in the web app to get the access token from the web api. My plan is, that the access token is stored in a cookie, so that the web app can use it to access the web api, if needed. Can I use this access token for the authentication and authorization at the web app too? Maybe something like creating a custom `SignInManager` and `UserManager`, or give the web app database access and use the standard asp.net identity. Or is there another better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought, that the web app can use this access token for authorization, but I don't now how to set up the middleware in asp.net core.

There's nothing in ASP.NET Core that will help you implement a "resource owner password credentials grant" client. Luckily, it's something you can easily do yourself with `HttpClient`. Here's how you could do that (note that error handling is left as an exercise):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string username, string password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        return View("MissingCredentials");
    }

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://server.com/connect/token");
    request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["client_id"] = "your client_id",
        ["client_secret"] = "your client_secret",
        ["grant_type"] = "password",
        ["username"] = "username",
        ["password"] = "password"
    });

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request, notification.Request.CallCancelled);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    var token = payload.Value<string>("access_token");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        return View("InvalidCredentials");
    }

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Cookies");
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", token));

    return SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), "Cookies");
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could consider using an interactive flow like the authorization code, which would allow you to use the OpenID Connect client middleware developed by the ASP.NET team. You can give this [OpenIddict MVC sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/master/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Client) a try to understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I did not make myself clear. My web api and web app are separated. I am able to receive the access token from my web api using a HttpClient, but I want to use this access token for the authorization at the web app and not only for the web api. But maybe it's better to use the standard asp.net core identity for the authorization here, even if the web api isn't the only instance with db access anymore.

Comment: `but I want to use this access token for the authorization at the web app and not only for the web api`> the question is "how do you want to flow the access token from the client to the Web application"? Unlike an authentication cookie, an access token is something clients must actively send (e.g attached to the `Authorization` header or to the query string).

Comment: Yes, this is part of my question. I thought about saving the token in a cookie, but I am not sure if this is a good Idea, because normally you include the access token in the header of a request. But it would be nice to have only one access token, which can be used for both web app and web api. I am not sure about the best practice. I am still in a conceptual phase and could aslo implement asp.net core identity at the web app, which connects to the api with the access token gained with the help of your solution. But then there are 2 ways of authentication and two instances with db access.

Comment: You should really update your question to include more details about your requirements, that are really unclear: is your Web app a SPA app? A good old MVC app? Will it have API controllers?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just edited my question with more details.

Comment: Then the approach described in my answer is the right one: your Web app must send a token request containing the user password to get back an access token. You're then free to persist the user identity in an authentication cookie.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I persist the identity in an authentication cookie?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you could handle that in a controller action. That said, you should strongly consider using an interactive flow like the authorization code flow. Give the MVC sample a try.